# Is there any way to save helpful questions on S.O. for easy retrieval?

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

I bookmark the crap out of stackoverflow, but i'm wondering if there's a way to save the questions directly in my account or something so I can browse them later if I need to. I dont like having the bookmarks associated with a particular browser or computer.

Sorry if this has been asked before

Comment: See the little star under the question score? Clicking that adds it to your favorites. View them on your profile screen.

Comment: You can mark them as favourites (star under the vote buttons

Comment: dear god i'm an idiot. thank you

Comment: Unless you know the keywords it can be difficult to find these things; glad you've got your answer